# Is there a good algorithm for this graph problem?

Tags: algorithm, graph

There's an undirected graph with weights on edges (weights are non-negative integers and their sum isn't big, most are 0). I need to divide it into some number of subgraphs (let's say graph of 20 nodes to 4 subgraphs of 5 nodes each) in a way that minimizes sum of weights of edges between different subgraphs.

This sounds vaguely like the minimum cut problem, but not quite close enough.

In alternative formulation - there's a bunch of buckets, all items belong to exactly two buckets, and I need to partition buckets into bucket groups in a way that minimizes number of items in more than one bucket group. (nodes map to buckets, edge weights map to duplicate item counts)

Comment: Well, to minimize the sum of edges between the subgraphs is the same as to maximize the sum of edges within subgraphs. What exactly are the constraints for splitting the graph?

Comment: Is this an image segmentation problem?

Comment: Do you really mean "good" or do you mean "optimal"? I can think of a few "good" approaches :)

Comment: Hamish: Subgraphs cannot contain more nodes than specified (must be equally sized, possibly +-1 if node count is uneven).

Jacob: It's a problem of merging big datasets from multiple servers in parallel and without running out of diskspace ;-)

dvogel: Greedy construction one node at a time while keeping 50 best results seems to work well enough in practice, I was just wondering if it was maybe some well-known problem with a better algorithm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the minimum k-cut problem, and is NP hard. Here's a greedy heuristic that will guarantee you a 2-1/k approximation:

While the graph has fewer than k components:
  1) Find a min-cut in each component
  2) Split the component with the smallest weight min-cut.

The problem is studied in this paper: http://www.cc.gatech.edu/~vazirani/k-cut.ps

Comment: Does this cater to the restriction that the subgraph sizes should be equal (or +-1)? Seems like we should be able to reduce it both ways to prove NP-hardness and give algorithms using min k-cut.